# add counter to tcbset beamer

Tags: beamer, counters, tcolorbox

I have defined a `tcbset` as follows:

```
\tcbset{%
  left=6mm, right=6mm, top=6mm, bottom=6mm, middle=4mm,
}

\tcbset{%
  outerlayer/.style={%
    enhanced,
    sharpish corners=all,
    colbacktitle=dcol, 
    coltitle=white, coltext=dcol,
    left=1mm, 
    right=1mm, 
    top=1mm,
    bottom=1mm, 
    middle=4mm, 
    toptitle=1mm, 
    bottomtitle=1mm,
    fuzzy shadow={0mm}{0.9mm}{0.6mm}{0.2mm}{black!20!Grey}, % top
    fuzzy shadow={0mm}{-0.6mm}{-0.1mm}{0.2mm}{black!40!Grey}, % bottomSmall
    fuzzy shadow={0mm}{-0.2mm}{-0.2mm}{0.2mm}{black!20!Grey}, % bottomBig
    title filled, boxrule=0mm, %
    segmentation code={\path[draw=BGrey](segmentation.west) -- (segmentation.east);}
  },
  innerlayer/.style={outerlayer,
    noparskip, 
    breakable, 
    colback=dcol,%
    coltitle=black,
    coltext=white, 
    fonttitle={\bfseries \scshape}, 
  bottomtitle=1mm}
}

\newtcolorbox{card}[1][]{%
  outerlayer,
  title=#1,
}

\newtcolorbox{hlcard}[1][]{%
  innerlayer,box align=base,
   #1
}
```

Now, I want an optional counter to the at the left of the title. 
I mean something like:

```
\newtcolorbox{card}[1][<counter here>][]{%
      outerlayer,
      title=#2,
    }
```

And the counter should appear when the first optional box is given (any better approach is welcome).

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you make a compilable MWE?

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide a complete and compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), I tried to build it.

Because of that, I don't know your color definition, hence I used `red` instead of `dcol`, `gray` instead of `Grey` and `blue` instead of `BGrey`.

`tcolorbox` has an `auto counter` option which allows counting a specific type of box (in your example `card`, and not `hlcard`).

You can use `\thetcbcounter` to put automatically the number after the title.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{mwe}% <-- for testing purpose only, delete it
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{%
    left=6mm, right=6mm, top=6mm, bottom=6mm, middle=4mm,
}

\tcbset{%
    outerlayer/.style={%
        enhanced,
        sharpish corners=all,
        colbacktitle=red, 
        coltitle=white, coltext=red,
        left=1mm, 
        right=1mm, 
        top=1mm,
        bottom=1mm, 
        middle=4mm, 
        toptitle=1mm, 
        bottomtitle=1mm,
        fuzzy shadow={0mm}{0.9mm}{0.6mm}{0.2mm}{black!20!gray}, % top
        fuzzy shadow={0mm}{-0.6mm}{-0.1mm}{0.2mm}{black!40!gray}, % bottomSmall
        fuzzy shadow={0mm}{-0.2mm}{-0.2mm}{0.2mm}{black!20!gray}, % bottomBig
        title filled, boxrule=0mm, %
        segmentation code={\path[draw=blue](segmentation.west) -- (segmentation.east);}
    },
    innerlayer/.style={outerlayer,
        noparskip, 
        breakable, 
        colback=red,%
        coltitle=black,
        coltext=white, 
        fonttitle={\bfseries \scshape}, 
        bottomtitle=1mm}
}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{card}[1][]{%
    outerlayer,
    title={#1~\thetcbcounter},
}

\newtcolorbox{hlcard}[1][]{%
    innerlayer,box align=base,
    #1
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \begin{card}[Title of the card box]
        Text of card box upper part
        \tcblower
        lower part
    \end{card}
    \begin{hlcard}
        hlcard box with no counter
    \end{hlcard}
    \begin{card}[Title of another card box]
        Text of anothe card box upper part
        \tcblower
        lower part
    \end{card}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]